# Tailwind - Is there a way to disable preflight ONLY for ul / ol lists?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

In tailwind, `ul` and `ol` lists are unstyled by default due to preflight. I need lists to work as they normally do before preflight strips it to nothing. Specifically, I need bullets to appear and nested bullets to appear and be indented. Putting the following code in `application.tailwind.css` doesn't work (nested lists don't appear as they should):

```
@layer base {
  ul, ol {
    list-style: revert;
  }
}
```

Expected:

- item1

  - item2
- item3

Current:

- item1
- item2
- item3

is there any way to make lists appear normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `revert` to `margin` and `padding` makes lists behave as they did prior to tailwind preflight.

In `application.tailwind.css`

```
@layer base {
  ul, ol {
    list-style: revert;
    margin: revert;
    padding: revert;
  }
}
```